# Similarity measure for time series

Tags: time-series, similarities, dynamic-time-warping

How can I recognize patterns with different sizes in a time-series? Imagine that I have a template pattern and I need to find that pattern in a symbolic representation of the time-series (stock market prices). However, the pattern can appear with different lengths. I found [dynamic time warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55083/dynamic-time-warping-and-normalization), for example. Is this a possible solution?

Comment: a naive solution would be to generate several templates in different scales, and convolve with the time series several times.

Comment: What is a symbolic representation of the time-series?

Comment: The naive solution is my current idea. When I say symbolic representation, something like taking the time derivative of the time-series and mapping the value to a given symbol.Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are no patterns in stock markets.